# Tailgate needed for Ontario safety certificate?

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, tailgate

I have a 2010 Silverado that I want to get certified in Ontario. The truck doesn't have a tailgate.

Does the truck need to have a tailgate installed in order for it to pass the safety?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.fasken.com/en/knowledge/2017/01/automotivegroupbulletin-20170109 (Revisions to Electrical Systems and Vehicle Body), says "All equipment must be in good working condition, not be missing, nor present an unsafe or hazardous condition to individuals who may be exposed to the vehicle."

My interpretation is that it will fail on a missing tailgate - but you could call the testing center in advance and ask them the question before booking in.

Comment: Given that installing a truck-bed camper would necessitate removing the tailgate, and a missing tailgate does not create an "unsafe or hazardous condition" to anyone, I'm not sure I believe that source.